# how to change the position of textfield in adf forms?

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

Hi friends i am using jdev 11g release2 (11.1.2.4.0).I want to create a registration form from dragging datas from data control and my question was how to change or move the position of textfield in that form into different areas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using various layout components to achieve the layout you want, and remember that layout components can be nested to create more complex layouts.

See some examples here:
http://jdevadf.oracle.com/adf-richclient-demo/faces/feature/layoutForm.jspx
You can use the view source menu to see how they achieved that.

http://jdevadf.oracle.com/adf-richclient-demo/faces/feature/layoutBasics.jspx

Answer (score 0):

Please be a bit more clear in your query. From what I was able to make out:
You can either use the "code view" of the JDev to move the code which represents the component to a different location or use the "Design view" to drag and move the component. 
I would recommend the first approach as it makes it easier to manage the code/layout

Answer (score 0):

You can change the position of the fields within the form or you can drag them out. However for this you should try out some tests and see which suits you best. I think if you surround each attribute with "Panel label and message" you will have a better view of your page.